# Is possible to add a list to the ANNIE Gazetteer in Gate 8.5.1?

Tags: nlp, gate

Switching to the new release of Gate (from the 8.4.1 to the 8.5.1), it seems not possible to modify the ANNIE gazetteer adding a new list. 
In fact in the gazetter editor the box for adding a new list it's disabled. 
I've tried also to look for the files usually located in 
`C:\Program Files\GATE_Developer_8.4.1\plugins\ANNIE\resources\gazetteer`, but the plugin folder is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since GATE 8.5, plugin's resource files of *new format plugins* cannot be directly modified anymore. You have to extract them to a new location on your local file system and load particular GATE PRs with these extracted files. Then you can modify the extracted files as you like...

See also https://gate.ac.uk/userguide/sec:developer:plugins

> Some plugins also contain ﬁles which are used to conﬁgure the
>   resources. For example, the ANNIE plugin contains the resources for
>   the ANNIE Gazetteer and the ANNIE NE Transducer (amongst other
>   things). While often these ﬁles can be used straight from within the
>   plugin, it can be useful to edit them, either to add missing
>   information or as a starting point for delveloping new resources etc.
>   **To extract a copy of these resource ﬁles from a plugin simply select
>   it in the plugin manager and then click the download resources button
>   shown under the list of resources the plugin deﬁnes.** This button will
>   only be enabled for plugins which contain such ﬁles. After clicking
>   the button you will be asked to select a directory into which to copy
>   the ﬁles. You can then edit the ﬁles as needed before using them to
>   conﬁgure a new instance of the appropriate processing resource.